# Why network is not learning with this loss?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I've been playing around a bit with Pytorch and have created a convolutional network with a total of 3 layers. I created a loss function that takes the results from the first layer and tries to minimize the norm.
So that view2 displays the data after the first layer in a matrix.
During learning, the error did not change at all, and the city was equal to 1 the whole time.
I know that this code doesn't make sense, but I am very intersting to her very this code is not working.

```
data = sio.loadmat('ORL_32x32.mat')
x, y = data['fea'], data['gnd']
x, y = data['fea'].reshape((-1, 1, 32, 32)), data['gnd']
y = np.squeeze(y - 1)  # y in [0, 1, ..., K-1]
class ConvAutoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvAutoencoder, self).__init__()
        ## encoder layers ##
        # conv layer (depth from 3 --> 16), 3x3 kernels
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 3, 3)  
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(3 ,3, 3)  
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, 3)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, 3)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        return x

    def test1(self, x):
      x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
      x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
      return x
    
    def test2(self, x):
      x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
      x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
      x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
      x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
      return x

def my_loss(novi2):
    
    return torch.tensor(LA.norm(novi2)).to(device)


model = ConvAutoencoder().to(device)

epochs = 950; 
lossList = []
view2 = np.zeros((576,400))
view3 = np.zeros((576,400))
losses = torch.tensor(0.).to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
if not isinstance(x, torch.Tensor):
  x = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
x = x.to(device)
if isinstance(y, torch.Tensor):
  y = y.to('cuda').numpy()
K = len(np.unique(y))
for epoch in range(epochs):
        view2 = np.zeros((576,400))
        view3 = np.zeros((576,400))
        output = model.test2(x.to(device)).cpu().detach().numpy()
        output1 = model.test1(x.to(device)).cpu().detach().numpy()
        for i in range(numclass):
            lovro = output[i]
            lovro =lovro[[0]]
            lovro = lovro.squeeze(axis = 0)
            lovro = lovro.flatten()
    
            for j in range(576):
              view2[j][i] = lovro[j]
        for i in range(numclass):
            lovro = output[i]
            
           
        loss = my_loss(view2)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
      
        print('Epoch %02d' %
                  (epoch))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you implemented your loss does not really look "differentiable". I am putting it in quotation marks because what you are observing is a difference between mathematical diffentiation and backpropagation. There is no functional dependency in the underlying graph of computation between your variables and your loss. The reason for that is because you used an array, where you **copied** values into. So while your loss depends on values of "view2" it does not depend on values of outputs of your model. You have to avoid **any value assignments** when defining your computation.

```
x = np.array([0])
x[0] = output_of_network
loss = LA.norm(x) # wrong

loss = LA.norm(output_of_network) # correct
```